# Are there any foundational ruby or rails tutorials that deliberately avoid using shorthand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shorthand

When trying to introduce people to Rails and they go away and try the Getting Started tutorial, they all come back with the same questions around "what IS this" and what's going on under the covers.

What I've found is their introduction to ruby and rails is hampered or fumbled by the conventions to:

1. Not include parentheses around function parameters
2. Using symbols not strings
3. Using colons when specifying name-value-pairs in hashes rather than `=>`

Are there any introduction guides to ruby (and rails?) that deliberately include parentheses, strings not symbols etc to aid easier transition.. and then remove them later?

Thanks

Comment: The book is 10 years old and out of print, but I really love "Ruby for Rails" from David A. Black. It gives you more than enough knowledge about Ruby to perfectly grasp the Rails coding style. As for your question, I supposed Rails is written the way it is, and it wouldn't be productive to modify the coding style just to make it easier for people coming from Java/Javascript/C/....

Comment: I have found the free code school ruby courses really helpful: [Try Ruby](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-ruby) and [Rails for Zombies](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux) as well as the Michael Hartl [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). These do not specifically have the coding style you specify though. I would agree with Eric, I am unsure if it is productive to change the coding style even though it may be difficult for beginners from different languages to grasp.

Comment: If you are a Rubocop user (and don't disable the warnings) you'll come to appreciate colons vs the old style hash rockets.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is famous for getting rid of code related things out of way so that developers can focus on their problem solving instead of programming syntax.

I understand the issue here you are describing since this is an important point in almost all other languages, but having parentheses or not should not be the concern at all for the new beginners in Rails world. If they come up with those questions, you can try to explain that In Ruby (and Rails), there can be multiple ways to solve a problem, and multiple ways to write it. They can pick whichever is easier to remember for them.

While learning Ruby on Rails, most important part is to understand fundamental concept of how the flow works not the details. This is also one of the most important features of Ruby (and Rails)

It is readable, and flexible.

As for the tutorial recommendation, I learned a lot from this book.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, there is something called "Convention over Configuration." You have to accept these conventions as they are important when you actually work in a team and be part of actual productions.

As whizzkid already mentioned, focus on the fundamental concept of the flows and those syntaxes will come naturally. For beginners, I recommend ruby on rails guide, which I think is the best tutorial ever written for beginners.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

After this one, I recommend the same tutorial that Whizzkid posted, which goes a deeper than the first tutorial that I recommended.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/